# using css class in js to redirect after certain number of clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to expand on previous js code you all helped me out with in the past. The code creates a slideshow of cars and their pricing on a webpage, pulling the data from a mysql db. I had it working where it would redirect to a new page after a minute of time, but now I want the redirect to happen when the total number of plays equals the number of slides * 2. I am not experienced with js and any help would be great...

Here is the code that creates slideshow... (jscript.js)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var slideWidth = 1280;
      var slides = $('.slide');
      var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
      // Remove scrollbar in JS
      $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');
      // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
      slides
        .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
        // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
        .css({
          'float' : 'left',
          'width' : slideWidth
        });
      // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
      $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
      // Insert controls in the DOM
      $('#slideshow')
        .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl"></span>')
        .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl"></span>');
      // Hide left arrow control on first load
      manageControls(currentPosition);
      // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
      $('.control')
        .bind('click', function(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
        'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
            }, function() {
            // if last slide then move the pointer to 1st slide
            if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides-1) {
                currentPosition = -1;
            }
        });
      });

      window.setInterval(function() {
        $('#rightControl.control').click();
        }, 3000);

      // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
      function manageControls(position){
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
        // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
        if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{$('#rightControl').show() }
      } 

    });
```

Im thinking the code to redirect would be something like... (nextpage.js)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var slides = $('.slide');
      var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
      var clicks = $('.control');
      var slidesPlayed = clicks.length;

      if(numberOfSlides == (slidesPlayed * 2)){
        window.location.href = "https://www.cars.com";
        }

      });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freshly tested:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var slidesPlayed = 0;
      var whatever = 5;  //that would be the total slides * 2 if I understand what you want, but let's say it's 5 for this example
      $('#thetrigger').on("click", function() {
          slidesPlayed++;

          console.log(slidesPlayed);

          if(slidesPlayed >= whatever){
              window.location.href = "https://www.cars.com";
          }
      });
});
```

If you click #trigger whatever times, you get redirected.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I couldn't get this code working :/ . I put the code on a  new page, saved as a .js file and include in the js file just after the closing body tag on the .php file. Any ideas?

Comment: If you replace "whatever" with as many click as you want it to take, and "#thetrigger" with the actual id of the elements you click, this code will redirect you to cars.com. This I am certain of.

Comment: Well yes, you just typed it. Assuming your variable numberOfSlides up in the code does actually contain the number of slides. Does it ?

Comment: my mistake. I didn't replace the element placeholder you put of #thetrigger. It is now working. Thank you very much for all your help!